# Spring boot project builds in intellij bud not via docker-compose up (Java version)

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, intellij-idea

So i have a problem running my application on docker, im totally fine running it from my intellij. Bud cant get it working when using docker.

Error that i get :

> app_1    | [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile und: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 12 not supported -> [Help 1]

How come? Here is the pom important part:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And in here i have docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:12-jdk
```

Contains nothing else, my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
   container_name: some-nginx
   image: nginx:1.13
   restart: always
   ports:
   - 8080:8080
   - 443:443
   volumes:
   - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
   depends_on:
   - app

  mysql:
   container_name: some-mysql
   image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
   environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: workaround
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
   ports:
   - "3307:3307"
   restart: always

  app:
    restart: always
    build: ./
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

And my structure :

[image]

Docker command run :

[image]

Intellij works fine :

[image]

Java version on my pc (bud that has nothign to do with that i guess):

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Anyone knows what am i doing wrong here? Im kinda stuck on this.**

**Just few notes:**
I have tried  different namings for this verison like 12.0.1 etc bud still same issue, I  dont have any other  version of java on my pc and so far I didnt have any issue. Im using windows and regarding docker and nginx setup Im inspired by this git repo :
https://github.com/hellokoding/dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx?fbclid=IwAR3BP22BYLNEMw8Yhz9z64JQj-tMQ8fQTsK0vlRHU_WhpasebNrCqEQnckc

Comment: The Maven compiler plugin may not support release 12 yet.  Would 11 do for you?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Hi, well i would prefer 12 bud if i cant get it work i will ahve to use 11, bud how come it works in Intellij, If what you say is true it shouldnt right?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You are correct it doesnt seem to support it .. damn. I tried 11 and it works, Maybe intellij does some magic and ignores that pom line and thats why it looks like it works with 12. I guess i will have to do it with 11

Comment: IntelliJ only uses the Maven compiler plugin if you explicitly tell it to.  This is in your Maven build.

Comment: Wasnt aware of that  ;)

Comment: The Java ecosystem is so large there is always more to learn.  I would suggest that unless you really, really need newer language features then go for Java 11 (due to the Oracle Long Term Support upstream).

Comment: The image shows that you are not using JDK12 inside the container your building..I don't understand why you are building inside a container instead of building the app outside and just simply copying the final artifact into the container...

Comment: @khmarbaise im going after some tutorial, first day working with docker :) Now my issue is database bud that is another question for another time :D